# SAS: array and macro variables

Tags: sas

```
%let p1 = 1;
%let p2 = 2;
```

I would like to create a data set with the macro variable `p1` in the column `y1` and the macro variable `p2` in the column `y2` using a do loop.

Can you help me?

I tried the following:

```
data test;
    array y(2);
    do i = 1 to 2;
        y(i) = &&p&i;
    end;
run;
```

which results in the following error:

```
Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string,
              a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, INPUT, PUT.
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?  It seems likely that your problem can be accomplished without using macro variables like this at all.  Are you storing data in macro variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `i` is a dataset variable (not a macro variable) and so cannot be referenced by `&i`.

You could either change your `do` loop into a macro `%do` loop (and wrap in a macro) as this creates a macro variable or use the [`symget()` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202938.htm) to get the macro variable value based on the name of the macro variable as a string.

macro approach:

```
%macro t;
data test;
    %do i = 1 %to 2;
        y&i = &&p&i;
    %end;
run;
%mend t;
%t;
```

`symget` approach:

```
data test;
    array y(2);
    do i = 1 to 2;
        y(i) = symget("p" || put(i, 1.));
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

As the macro is actually creating the statements `y# = #;` before the data step is executed the array is a bit redundant (unless it is going to refer to variables with other names). I've added a `drop` statement to the second example it just removes the variable `i` from the output dataset.

---

Edit: Discussion of types

Macro variables do not have type, they contain text. SAS treats macro variables the same regardless of what you store in them `%let a = 1;` and `%let a = Cats;` are both storing text.

In general macro variables are used to substitute the text you store in them into a SAS program before it executes. In the first example above SAS evaluates the macro statements and resolves the macro variables before the data step is executed, it becomes:

```
data test;
    y1 = 1;
    y2 = 2;
run;
```

Used in this way the macro language can automate the writing of tedious or repetitive parts of base SAS programs when you down want to type stuff out by hand. With that in mind consider the situation where you want to pass a string into a dataset variable from a macro variable.

```
%let p1 = Canada;
```

The code above would complain about not variable called `canada` as it would try to resolve `y1 = Canada`. However, if you wrapped one (but not both) of your assignments in quotes it would work as expected: `y&i = "&&p&i";` (or `%let p1 = "Canada";`).

`symget()` will create a character variable (length $200.) if used as a new assignment, and it always returns a character value when used for accessing a macro variable.

---

In general macro variables are not a great method for storing/moving data, they are good for parametrising scripts if you have values that change the way your program works, but if you are moving a lot of data then there is probably a better approach available. As Joe notes above there may be a better way to approach your problem.

Comment: What if the macro variable value is a character i.e. &&p&i resolves to Canada?

Comment: Macro variables are all text, there is no concept of a type for macro variables. If you want to put the contents of a macro variable into a character dataset variable wrap it in double quotes: `dsVar = "&mVar."`, `symget` returns a character string.

Comment: Sorry Reeza, I assumed your comment was a question from OP. I've added a bit on types at the bottom.